# Table with percentage sign for a specific line

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am importing a table from a file and I would like to add a percentage sign for all figures on the third row.

The code works well for a specific cell in the table using the command

```
every row 2 column 0/.style
```

but when I use the following code instead, nothing happens :

```
every row no/.style
```

Here is the full code with the corresponding result :

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[every row 2 column 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\textbf{##1\%}}},col sep=&,row sep=\\]{
colA & colB & colC \\
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
33 & 43 & 12 \\
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt the approach given by Christian Feuersänger in [Pgfplotstable one row in bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130835/pgfplotstable-one-row-in-bold) to define a new style that lets you format individual rows:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    row style/.style 2 args={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
            \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
            \advance\count0 by1
            \ifnum\count0=#1
                \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    row style/.style 2 args={
        postproc cell content/.append code={%
            \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
            \advance\count0 by1\relax
            \ifnum\count0=#1
                \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row style={3}{@cell content=\bfseries #1\,\%},
    col sep=&,row sep=\\
]{
colA & colB & colC \\
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
33 & 43 & 12 \\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well ! However, is it possible to put the code \pgfplotstabletypeset[...]{...} in a macro ? I get troubles with the #1 when it is inside a macro.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example where the that happens?

Comment: I just found the answer to my own question about the #1 : i need to use ##1 instead. (see : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79705/using-1-literally-in-a-macro )

Comment: @Jake is it safe using `\count0` like that?  Wouldn't it be safer to create a counter for this style?  Or am I just being overly cautious?

Comment: I tried to add 'precision=0' in the pgfkeysalso command but it doen't work (with decimal values in the table). Did I make a mistake ?

Comment: @Laurent: Are you trying to round the values only in the last row?

Comment: @Jake In fact, I tried it for the whole table, but it doen't apply to the last row. I would be interested to see how it can be configured for the last row only since the 'intuitive' solution of adding 'precision=0' doen't work.