# How to display every 4th row in a large data file using pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

**Question:** I am trying to select certain rows, similar to this question [Selecting rows to be displayed with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/selecting-rows-to-be-displayed-with-pgfplotstable?rq=1), however I am not sure how I would go about doing it. I want to display only every 4th row. Something like `skip rows between index` but more automated than that (the file is fairly long). I have attempted to use the code below code, but I am at a loss as to how I would output only every 4th row (starting from 1 (ie: 1, 5, 9, etc). I assume some type of math operator would work, but how?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
 obs      number
  1         2
  2         5
  3         3
  4         2
  5         4
  6         1
  7         2
  8         5
  9         3
  10        2
  11        4
  12        1
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{obs}\of{\loadedtable}
    \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=??\relax %Use some seq operator?
      \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse
    \fi}
]{\loadedtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the regular `Mod` operation for this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
 obs      number
  1         2
  2         5
  3         3
  4         2
  5         4
  6         1
  7         2
  8         5
  9         3
  10        2
  11        4
  12        1
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{obs}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathparse{int(Mod(\pgfplotsretval,4)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax
      \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse
    \fi}
]{\loadedtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, make it `\pgfmathresult=1`.

Comment: Note that the use of `\pgfplotstablegetelem` might be very inefficient, especially for "large tables" (unless "large" means <50 rows). But since obs is more-or-less equivalent to `\pgfplotstablerow`, you may want to prefer `\pgfplotstablerow`

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Indeed I remember your warning for that in the manual too, I was just replicating OP's code.

Comment: @Luke FYI; consider Christian's comment seriously :)

Comment: @percusse Hmm, makes sense. I was wondering why the compiling was taking longer than usual. I'll look into it.