# filecontents: select rows of group to display

Tags: conditionals, external-files

I have a file that contains 1,000 rows of product data. I want to select only a specific product type to print in my document.

Minimal code in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{product.tex}

%Type =1,2...10
No.,Type ,Name , Description
1, 1, A1,D1
….
30, 1, A1, D30
31, 2, A2, D31
…
131,2, A2, D131
132,3,A3,D132
….
249,4,A4,D249
…
1.000,10, A10,D1000

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%Need command can CHOOSE Type = 1 and/or 2, and/or 3, ...10
%i choose type = 1 & 3
\include{run.tex}
\end{document}
```

Product Types range from 1, 2, ..., 10. And in `run.tex`:

```
%Display like:

Name[i] & Description[j]
```

`main.pdf` result:

```
Type = 1

A1 - D1

…

A1 - D30

Type = 3

A3 - D132

…

A3 - D248
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{product.tex}
%Type =1,2...10
No,Type,Name,Description
1,1,A1,D1
2,1,A1,D2
3,1,A1,D3
30,1,A1,D30
31,2,A2,D31
131,2,A2,D131
132,3,A3,D132
133,3,A3,D133
134,3,A3,D134
249,4,A4,D249
1000,10,A10,D1000
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{products}{product.tex}

\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{%
  \par
  \section*{Type #1}
  \DTLforeach*
    [\DTLiseq{\Type}{#1}]% Condition
    {products}% Database
    {\No=No,\Type=Type,\Name=Name,\Description=Description}{%
    \noindent\Name \quad \Description\par
  }% 
}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\printtype{1}

Some breaking text here.

\printtype{3}

And then some final text.

\end{document}
```

The `\printtype{<type>}` command uses `\DTLforeach` to cycle through the `products` database and print only items where the `\Type` equals `<type>`. You can format the presentation however you want.

Comment: Thank you. What is code if i need 2 condition (type = range (1-4) and No =1) do A) ; (type = range (1-4) and No != 1) do B) . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer heavily based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43826/121799). The main point here is to remark that you need to do `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` in order to loop over the types you want typeset, and not `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{product.dat}
No.,Type,Name,Description
1, 1, A1,D1
2, 1, A1,D2
30, 1, A1, D30
31, 2, A2, D31
131,2, A2, D131
132,3,A3,D132
249,4,A4,D249
1.000,10, A10,D1000
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{product.dat}{\data}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,3}{
\subsection*{\boldmath$\text{Type}=#1$}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
row predicate/.code={%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{##1}{Type}\of{\data}
  \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=#1\relax
  \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}
]{\data}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]