# Select page number of print command of DTLforeach, filecontent?

Tags: filecontents

My last post: [filecontents: select rows of group to display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476354/filecontents-select-rows-of-group-to-display)

And @Werner wrote brilliant solution for me with command : "print"

His MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{product.tex}
%Type =1,2...10
No,Type,Name,Description
1,1,A1,D1
2,1,A1,D2
3,1,A1,D3
30,1,A1,D30
31,2,A2,D31
131,2,A2,D131
132,3,A3,D132
133,3,A3,D133
134,3,A3,D134
249,4,A4,D249
1000,10,A10,D1000
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{products}{product.tex}

\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{%
  \par
  \section*{Type #1}
  \DTLforeach*
    [\DTLiseq{\Type}{#1}]% Condition
    {products}% Database
    {\No=No,\Type=Type,\Name=Name,\Description=Description}{%
    \noindent\Name \quad \Description\par
\newpage
  }% 
}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\printtype{1}

Some breaking text here.

\printtype{3}

And then some final text.

\end{document}
```

Now I want to select some page to PDF print, like `\includepdf[pages=5-10]`? Is possible with `\printtype` ? 
Ex:

```
\printtype{1}[pages=1-3]

\printtype{2}[pages=2-4]

\printtype{3}[pages=1]
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any pdf and nothing that could have pages except of the current document that will be generated from your code... So, I am afraid that your question is not really clear.

Comment: @koleygr i just added "\newpage" and you can see pdf with many pages