# pgfplots: Using "x filter" to decrease point density of plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, axis, domain

The user [esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484762/78784) has posted a nice approach on how to increase point density for a certain range of data points while the remaining plot keeps low point density by using `x filter`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Time;Value
    0.000;24.3
    0.008;67.1
    0.017;74.7
    0.025;71.3
    0.033;66.5
    0.042;61.8
    0.050;57.7
    0.058;54.6
    0.067;52.2
    0.075;49.7
    0.083;47.8
    0.092;46.3
    0.100;45.3
    0.108;44.0
    0.117;43.0
    0.125;42.3
    0.133;41.8
    0.142;41.2
    0.150;40.7
    0.158;40.3
    0.167;39.8
    0.175;39.7
    0.183;39.3
    0.192;39.0
    0.200;38.8
    0.208;38.5
    0.217;38.5
    0.225;38.2
    0.233;38.1
    0.242;37.9
    0.250;37.8
    0.258;37.7
    0.267;37.5
    0.275;37.3
    0.283;37.0
    0.292;37.0
    0.300;37.0
    0.308;36.8
    0.317;36.5
    0.325;36.6
    0.333;36.3
    0.342;36.5
    0.350;36.2
    0.358;36.2
    0.367;36.1
    0.375;36.0
    0.383;35.9
    0.392;35.9
    0.400;35.7
    0.408;35.5
    0.417;35.4
    0.425;35.4
    0.433;35.3
    0.442;35.2
    0.450;35.1
    0.458;34.9
    0.467;35.0
    0.475;34.9
    0.483;34.9
    0.492;34.8
    0.500;34.7
    0.508;34.5
    0.517;34.3
    0.525;34.4
    0.533;34.5
    0.542;34.3
    0.550;34.2
    0.558;34.2
    0.567;34.1
    0.575;34.1
    0.583;33.9
    0.592;33.9
    0.600;33.7
    0.608;33.8
    0.617;33.8
    0.625;33.7
    0.633;33.6
    0.642;33.5
    0.650;33.5
    0.658;33.5
    0.667;33.3
    0.675;33.3
    0.683;33.2
    0.692;33.2
    0.700;33.1
    0.708;33.1
    0.717;33.0
    0.725;33.0
    0.733;32.9
    0.742;32.9
    0.750;32.8
    0.758;32.7
    0.767;32.8
    0.775;32.6
    0.783;32.6
    0.792;32.5
    0.800;32.5
    0.808;32.4
    0.817;32.4
    0.825;32.4
    0.833;32.3
    0.842;32.1
    0.850;32.2
    0.858;32.1
    0.867;32.1
    0.875;32.0
    0.883;32.0
    0.892;32.0
    0.900;32.0
    0.908;32.0
    0.917;31.8
    0.925;31.8
    0.933;31.8
    0.942;31.7
    0.950;31.7
    0.958;31.6
    0.967;31.6
    0.975;31.7
    0.983;31.6
    0.992;31.6
    1.000;31.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1>0.3 && mod(\coordindex,10)!=0 ? nan :#1}}]
            \addplot table[col sep = semicolon,x=Time,y=Value] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

Assumed I have a huge amount of data points (e.g. from measuring several values with an interval of 30 seconds for a time span of 7 days = 20160 data sets). Only the points with values higher than 40 are relevant.

Would it be possible to apply the following properties for the plot to decrease its file size:

- Set `each nth point = {1}` for all points if point value is higher than 40
- Set `each nth point = {30}` for all points if point value is lower than 40

Or, tried to explain in programmers language:

*IF `point-value` > 40, THEN `each nth point = {1}`; ELSE `each nth point = {30}`;*

---

With this I try to reduce the plot file size to make compiling possible at all. Furthermore, the basic "data noise" without importance is displayed in less precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering why you are using an `x` filter rather than an `y filter` if you want to filter out points that are below a certain value. If I set an `y filter`, I get

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Time;Value
    0.000;24.3
    0.008;67.1
    0.017;74.7
    0.025;71.3
    0.033;66.5
    0.042;61.8
    0.050;57.7
    0.058;54.6
    0.067;52.2
    0.075;49.7
    0.083;47.8
    0.092;46.3
    0.100;45.3
    0.108;44.0
    0.117;43.0
    0.125;42.3
    0.133;41.8
    0.142;41.2
    0.150;40.7
    0.158;40.3
    0.167;39.8
    0.175;39.7
    0.183;39.3
    0.192;39.0
    0.200;38.8
    0.208;38.5
    0.217;38.5
    0.225;38.2
    0.233;38.1
    0.242;37.9
    0.250;37.8
    0.258;37.7
    0.267;37.5
    0.275;37.3
    0.283;37.0
    0.292;37.0
    0.300;37.0
    0.308;36.8
    0.317;36.5
    0.325;36.6
    0.333;36.3
    0.342;36.5
    0.350;36.2
    0.358;36.2
    0.367;36.1
    0.375;36.0
    0.383;35.9
    0.392;35.9
    0.400;35.7
    0.408;35.5
    0.417;35.4
    0.425;35.4
    0.433;35.3
    0.442;35.2
    0.450;35.1
    0.458;34.9
    0.467;35.0
    0.475;34.9
    0.483;34.9
    0.492;34.8
    0.500;34.7
    0.508;34.5
    0.517;34.3
    0.525;34.4
    0.533;34.5
    0.542;34.3
    0.550;34.2
    0.558;34.2
    0.567;34.1
    0.575;34.1
    0.583;33.9
    0.592;33.9
    0.600;33.7
    0.608;33.8
    0.617;33.8
    0.625;33.7
    0.633;33.6
    0.642;33.5
    0.650;33.5
    0.658;33.5
    0.667;33.3
    0.675;33.3
    0.683;33.2
    0.692;33.2
    0.700;33.1
    0.708;33.1
    0.717;33.0
    0.725;33.0
    0.733;32.9
    0.742;32.9
    0.750;32.8
    0.758;32.7
    0.767;32.8
    0.775;32.6
    0.783;32.6
    0.792;32.5
    0.800;32.5
    0.808;32.4
    0.817;32.4
    0.825;32.4
    0.833;32.3
    0.842;32.1
    0.850;32.2
    0.858;32.1
    0.867;32.1
    0.875;32.0
    0.883;32.0
    0.892;32.0
    0.900;32.0
    0.908;32.0
    0.917;31.8
    0.925;31.8
    0.933;31.8
    0.942;31.7
    0.950;31.7
    0.958;31.6
    0.967;31.6
    0.975;31.7
    0.983;31.6
    0.992;31.6
    1.000;31.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        y filter/.expression={(y < 45 && mod(\coordindex,10) >0)? nan : y}]
            \addplot table[col sep = semicolon,x=Time,y=Value] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for your help marmot! :-) I didn't know that there is also a `y filter` available. Just one last question: In case my table has more than only two columns, how can I specify which column should be chosen as the key-column for the `y filter`? Or does `y filter` select exactly the `y value`-column that you selected within `addplot`?

Comment: @Dave You're welcome! You are saying `table[col sep = semicolon,x=Time,y=Value]` so `y` comes from the column `Value`. Notice that you can use `visualization depends on` in order to also access data from other columns, but so far I have never used this in combination with filters.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much and happy easter! :-)

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Does it make sense at all to decrease the amount of points with the aim to reduce LaTeX memory usage (to be able compile larger plots)? Or doesn't the amount of points have any effect on LaTeX memory usage?

Comment: @Dave I do not know that, sorry.